# How to use servlet container in jenkins

Tags: java, servlets, jenkins

I see "servlet container" in jenkins security options. So how can I use this?

In my scenario, I have a team that they have their own username/password, I need ensure they can login using their own account. And we have an account system that manage accounts. So I need to write a java servlet that can connect the account system.

In jenkins, do I need to provide this java servlet? I searched for long time. but I can't find the exact way to use jenkins 'servlet container' security option.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to [Jenkins documentation "Managing Security"](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/security/).

According to the documentation :

You need to activate "**Delegate to servlet container**" option under "**Security Realm**" in "**Configure Global Security**".

> ### Security Realm
>
> By default Jenkins includes support for a few different Security
>   Realms:
>
> **Delegate to servlet container**
>
> For delegating authentication a servlet container running the Jenkins
>   master, such as Jetty. If using this option, please consult the
>   servlet container’s authentication documentation.

Comment: I see the "delegate to servlet container" says it uses container authentication, such as in tomcat, it depends on the  tomcat-user.xml, that means username/password are configured in the file,  How can I use this if I want to use third-party account system?

Comment: You should take a look to this : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html

Comment: I'm wondering how to use this option in the context of a K8s cluster...